# master detail and single view application mixed

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, master-detail, tabbed

I am new here and new to iOS, so my apologies in advance if my question is silly.
I have just finished a course on iOS and Xcode and learnt how to build the different types of apps, like master-detail, tabbed or single view applications. 
My question is : Is it possible to build an app that would be for example a master-detail app but would look like a tabbed one on one of the views and would look like a page-based on another view? In other words is it possible to create an app that would be a mix of several types ? I have Googled everywhere but I can't find anything. I may be using the wrong key words as on the top of that, I am French. I am not looking for precise explanations, just if somebody could point me in the right direction where to look and continue studying.
Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Well am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but you can take a look at this example. Its a combination of UISplitViewController & UITabBarController

[Custom UISplitViewController for iPad](http://www.alterplay.com/ios-dev-tips/2011/05/custom-uisplitviewcontroller-for-ipad.html)

Comment: Just found your answer. Thank you!